# Execute .db file with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, ios7

I have a sqlite script as a .db file and I want to execute it in order to create and fill coredata tables. There is a way to perform that with objective-C on a iPhone application ? Can't find a solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot mix plain SQLite and Core Data based SQLite.  Core Data uses a specific design for its tables that you should not try and replicate outside of Core Data.

Use Core Data to populate a Core Data SQLite file.

Comment: Thanks ! But how can I populate my coredata database with my sqlite database ?

Comment: Depends on your DB file. Consider how you would access it in Objective-C and then write migration code to get the data into Core Data.